# Saving logcat to a file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save the logcat contents to a file.

I seem to have this working using:

```
    try {
            File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logfile.log");
            filename.createNewFile();
            String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is it possible to print the datetime stamp that usually shows up in the logcat but isn't showing up in my file? Is it also possible to only print certain content for example only the "W" Warning lines? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Filtering Output](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput)

Answer (score 0):

I added the time and filtered by W's using:

```
            String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", filename.getAbsolutePath(), "-v", "time", "*:W"};
```